# PrimeFaces JSF library: Whole page inside a lightBox?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'd like to place a whole page inside a PrimeFaces library UI component `lightBox`.

For example I have:

- Normal_page.xhtml
- Popup_page.xhtml

Is it possible to launch Popup_page.xhtml from Normal_page.xhtml and display it inside lightBox so that Popup_page would be overlayed over Normal_page?

**p.s.**

I used to do this using `<p:dialog>` and `<ui:include>`, like so:

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="myPopup"...> 
    <ui:include src="/Popup_page.xhtml"/>
</p:dialog>
```

and

```
<p:commandButton onclick="myPopup.show();"/>
```

but this doesn't seem to work with `<p:lightBox>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these methods worked for me:

**LightBox inline method:**

```
<p:lightBox>
    <h:outputLink value="#">  
        <h:outputText value="Open Lightbox Popup (using inline)"/>  
    </h:outputLink>   
    <f:facet name="inline">
        <ui:include src="popup_Page.xhtml"/>
    </f:facet>
</p:lightBox>
```

**LightBox iframe method:**

```
<p:lightBox iframe="true">      
    <h:outputLink value="popup_Page.xhtml">  
        <h:outputText value="Open Lightbox Popup (using iframe)"/>  
    </h:outputLink>   
</p:lightBox>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried the first one and it works nice. One problem is that some actionListeners seem not to be fireing events as they did when I used `p:dialog`. So, it should all work as `p:dialog` with regards to functionality, only looks and window behaviour is different?